# wkhtmltopdf is not considering the --user-style-sheet command line parameter

Tags: html, css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

We have been using wkhtmltopdf in our application to generate PDF using HTML code.

This is how it is now in the config file:

`$V{html2pdf} = "/opt/project/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf -q -s Letter --load-error-handling ignore --javascript-delay 100 --encoding utf8 --zoom 0.8 --disable-external-links --disable-internal-links --header-font-size 8 --header-font-name Verdana --header-left '[date]' --header-right 'Page [page] of [toPage]' --print-media-type --dpi 600 --user-style-sheet $V{PROJECT_DIR}/assets/c1/css/pdf_report.css ";`

Recently we updated our servers to `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS` and also updated  wkhtmltopdf to a newer version that is `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 (with patched qt)`.

Now when I am try to generate a pdf, some of the html elements are displayed out of format. refer the screenshot.

[image: Text overlapping the border]

[image: Text overlapping the text and crossing over to next div]

This was not the case previously. 
So started investigating the issue. Found some answers related to the `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 (with patched qt)` and suggestion to add `--disable-smart-shrinking` command line directive to the config file. I did that and there was not change.

Finally decided to start changing the css rules in `--user-style-sheet $V{PROJECT_DIR}/assets/c1/css/pdf_report.css`. After changing couple of css rules, tried testing. But strangely, it is not taking into consideration the new rules.

```css
/* My Report heading ---- OLD */
table.formTablePdf td.title h5 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 /* Reset to black */
 color: #000 !important;
 line-height: 1.2em;
 text-align: right;
}

/* My Report heading ---- NEW */
table.formTablePdf td.title h5 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 1em;
 /* Reset to black */
 color: #000 !important;
 line-height: 1.2em;
 text-align: right;
  padding-right: 2em;
}
```

Is there some bug in that too.. I found that it is an issue in the windows OS. the file should be prefixed with `///`.

Let me know if I am doing anything wrong. Has anyone faced the same issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
It was due to the new behavior of `wkhtmltopdf` for `--dpi` parameter. When I removed this parameter, and added `--enable-smart-shrinking` I was able to get the alignment of the content correctly. I am still facing an issue with the width of the PDF. My Page has a div which has a dynamic horizontal scrollbar which has table with lot of columns. In the previous version of `wkhtmltopdf`, the document use to zoom out/scale completely and capture everything. So at 100% zoom you can't read anything. You need to zoom to get look at the content. Now that is not happening. I am not sure why. I need to still check.